# Image resize on iOS CrossMobile

Tags: ios, iphone, crossmobile

I want to put an Image on my Crossmobile application using the code bellow

```
    img=new UIImageView(new CGRect(15, 15, 66, 66));
    img.frame().setSize(new CGSize(66,66));
    img.setAutoresizingMask(2);
    img.sizeThatFits(new CGSize(33, 33));
```

When the image appears on the app,the size is much bigger than the size i have put in the code.
I found the UIImage on the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage.

How could i fix the size of the image, to fit on my imgview square size?

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- you have already set the size of the UIImageView. You don't need to define it when you construct it and then redefine the frame.
- the [autoresizingMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask) is used when the parent UIView changes size, it doesn't define the fitting properties of the current UIView
- the [sizeThatFits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits) selector just returns the optimum size, it doesn't change the image size.

What you actually need is to set the [contentMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode?language=objc), with its modes defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontentmode?language=objc). I suspect you need the `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit` mode?